# How to avoid generating intermediate files in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, output

I would like to know if it is possible to change the following script, such that "intermediate.tmp" is not generated as output:

To call the script on the command line:

```
./script.sh file1 file2
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_1=$1
FILE_2=$2

awk '{print $1,$2}' $FILE_1 > intermediate.tmp

awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $0; next} {print $0,h[$1]}' intermediate.tmp $FILE_2 > output.file
```

The awk scripts are not really important per se. I just want to know how to "feed" intermediate.tmp into the second awk command without generating an intermediate.tmp output file in addition to the desired output.file.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $1 OFS $2; next} {print $0,h[$1]}' "$FILE_1" "$FILE_2" > output.file
```

or less sensibly:

```
awk '{print $1,$2}' "$FILE_1" |
awk 'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $0; next} {print $0,h[$1]}' - "$FILE_2" > output.file
```